# setting up passport local strategy with postgresSQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, passport.js

I'm having issues setting up passport authentication with my server. I've used passportjs before but with mongodb. I'm currently trying to setup my local strategy with postgressql but have had no luck. When going to a login POST route with passport.authenticate(), I'm not getting a cookie sent back to me. I'm not sure if I setup my server correctly with passportJS and with my postgres database hosted via Heroku.

```
require('dotenv').config(); //In order to gain access to our .env file
//process.env.YELP_API_KEY
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json()); //This is going to allow us to access data stored in 'body' when making a post or put request
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const fs = require("fs"); //This is needed to convert sql files into a string
let port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//session-related libraries
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport"); //This is used for authentication
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");


//Setting up our session
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));


//Connection to database
const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: true
}); //This is used to connect to our remote postegres database hosted via Heroku


//initializing our session
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); //Telling our app to use passport for dealing with our sessions


//setting up our local strategy
passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({passReqToCallBack: true},( username, password, cb )=> {
    console.log("this is being executed");
    pool.query("SELECT id, username, password from users where username=$1", [username], (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            return cb(err);

        }
        if(result.rows.length > 0){
            const first = result.rows[0];
            bcrypt.compare(password, first.password, (err, res) => {
                if(res){
                    cb(null, {
                        id: first.id,
                        user: first.username
                    })
                }
                else {
                    cb(null, false);
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            cb(null, false);
        }
    })
}));



passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    console.log("serialize user is executing")
    done(null, user.id);
})

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    pool.query('SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE id = $1', [parseInt(id, 10)], (err, results) => {
        if(err) {
          return done(err)
        }

        done(null, results.rows[0])
      });
});


app.post("/api/login", (req, res) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info){
        console.log(user);
    });
})



app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Your app is running on port " + port);
});
```

Expected Results: user should be able to login with the post route "/api/login" but passport.authenticate is not working? Passport local strategy should also be correctly setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your route `app.post("/api/login", ....` the passport.authenticate needs an access to the `req` and `res`.

There's more than one way to make it work.

```
app.post("/api/login", (req, res) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info){
        console.log(user);
        // make sure to respond to the request
        res.send(user);
    })(req, res); // <= pass req and res to the passport
})

// or
// use it as a middleware
app.post("/api/login", passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.user);
    // make sure to respond to the request
    res.send(req.user);
})
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much for the help. I did what you suggested and tested my routes with postman and it works! A cookie and the user information was successfully sent back to me.